# Send Cookie with a URL fired from WebView in Android

Tags: android, cookies, mobile, webview

Let me explain the scenario first,

Say there is an an app where there is a content on which if you click, it will fire a URL (like http://some_host.com?param=val&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsearch.yahoo.com%20) and open a yahoo page in webview. When the URL is fired through webview no cookie is set in the request.

If I fire the same URL through chrome I am able to see the cookie set in the request. How can I achieve the same in webview. Please shed some light.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class **CookieManager** check further documentation at this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setAcceptCookie(boolean))

To enable it use below code:

```
CookieManager().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(myWebView,true)
```

Comment: I do not have access to the app's code. Is there any other way or some setting which will start passing cookies?